# Problema con redireccion de ruta, laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5

Estoy haciendo pruebas con un pequeño crud, pero al momento de cargar la url http://10.1.0.67:8080/usuarios/public/usuarios se queda en blanco, no se por donde mas revisar, ni a que se debe este problema.

```
  Route::resource('usuarios', 'UsuariosController');
  Route::get('api/v1/libros','UsuariosController@getUsuarios');
```

Comment: ¿Qué se supone que debe mostrar dicha vista, tiene contenido, carga datos obtenidos de una consulta?, pones 2 rutas ¿cual es la que la invoca?

Comment: Hacé un `dd('algo')` dentro de `UsuariosController` (supongo que en el index) para ver si al menos está llegando al controlador. Sino el problema está antes.

Comment: vee habia olvidado el dd() voy a hacer nuevas pruebas